# SPE How to add multiple items to package source

Tags: media-library, powershell-extensions

I'm writing a SPE script to package up all unused media library items under a specific folder (prior to deletion). I've found `New-Package` and `New-ItemSource` methods and know how to use them (to some extent). How can I add multiple items from a collection to a single ItemSource object?

My script so far looks like this:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\sitecore\media library\Project\ACME" -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder} |
Where-Object { ![Sitecore.Globals]::LinkDatabase.GetReferrerCount($_) -gt 0}


# Create package
$package = new-package "Unused Media Items";

# Set package metadata
$package.Sources.Clear();
$package.Metadata.Author = "ACME";
$package.Metadata.Publisher = "ACME";
$package.Metadata.Version = "1.0.0";
$package.Metadata.Readme = "";

$source = $items | New-ItemSource -Name 'Media' -InstallMode Overwrite
$package.Sources.Add($source);
```

It seems that when I pipe a collection object to `New-ItemSource` it only picks up the last item. It seems wrong to create a new itemsource object for each item, but maybe that is not an issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The script we use to bundle up SPE can be found here:
`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/Platform/Development/PowerShell Extensions Maintenance/Prepare Console Distribution`.

From the documentation [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/packaging/new-itemsource):

> Creates new Item source that can be added to a Sitecore package. Item provided to it is added as well as its subitems.

`New-ItemSource` returns a single object which represents the root node. Should probably just use `Get-Item`.

```powershell
Get-Item 'master:\templates\Modules\PowerShell Console' | 
    New-ItemSource -Name 'Master Item Templates' -InstallMode Overwrite
```

[image]

---

> Creates new Item source that can be added to a Sitecore package. This source only includes items explicitly added to it and not their children.

`New-ExplicitItemSource` returns a single object which represents the multiple entries. Use `Get-ChildItem`.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem 'master:\system\Modules\PowerShell' | 
    New-ExplicitItemSource -Name "Master Module Root" -InstallMode Merge -MergeMode Merge
```

[image]